# Verification for spherical coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given the integral to be integrated using spherical coordinates:
$$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \le z}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
I used the coordinates as follows:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x &= \rho\sin\varphi \cos\theta \\
y &= \rho\sin\varphi \sin\theta \\
z & =\rho\cos\varphi
\end{align}
\right.
$$

And the limits as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
0 \le &\varphi \le \pi \\
0 \le &\theta \le 2\pi
\end{align}
$$
and based on the condition given in the integral,
$$
0 \le \rho \le \cos\varphi
$$

I solved the integral to be 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\cos\varphi} \rho \cdot \rho^2 \sin\varphi \, d\rho \, d\varphi \, d\theta
$$

I solved this integral and the answer I got was $\frac{\pi}{5}$.  However, this is an online assignment and the system says it's incorrect (the answer is to two places of decimals and I tried with both $0.62$ and $0.63$) I tried doing this sum many times but I can't point the mistake out. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* Notice that the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq z$ also requires that $z \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in finding the bounds of integration after the change of variable. The condition
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\le z$$
translates to
$$\rho^2\le\rho\cos\varphi$$
and thus you have $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, $\rho\in[0,\cos\varphi]$ and $\varphi\in[0,\pi/2]$. This should give you the result of $\frac{\pi}{10}$.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you! I completely missed that step :)

Comment: @Artemisia In fact, my answer is exactly the same as the one of Tom. He answered first, so you should accept his instead of mine.